# Is there a way to change the directory where cd without argument change to?

Tags: zsh, cd-command

`cd` without argument change to the home directory. I'd like it to change to another one. Is there another way than writing a function to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cd () {
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        builtin cd /some/other/dir
    else
        builtin cd "$@"
    fi
}
```

This overrides `cd` with a function.  If the function gets no arguments, it calls the built in `cd` to change to a predefined directory.  Otherwise it runs the built in `cd` with the original arguments.

The *other* way to do it would be to change the value of `HOME` to some other directory, but that may also change the behavior of other utilities.

Comment: `builtin` is a `zsh builtin` command that does not behave as the template implementation from `ksh93`. If you mention commands that habe non-uniform behavior, please mention their limited usability.

Comment: @schily The user in the question runs `zsh`, not `ksh93`. What is the limited usability that you refer to?

Comment: This is a general UNIX platform and a general problem in answers is to mention methods that look as if they were useful on more than a single implementation of a standardized utility like a shell.

Comment: @schily The `zsh` shell is not standardized, but it is what the user is using. Feel free to post a POSIX solution. Note that `command cd "$@"` would work in `ksh93`, but not in `zsh`.

Comment: Your argument could be seen as valid if `zsh` was so different from other shells that your example did obviously not aply to other shells as well, or if the question did mention `zsh` in the headline.

Comment: @schily Could you please suggest an improvement or post your own answer. I fail to see where you're going with this.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried with another name (I didn't knew about `builtin`) and has issues with the completion. Reusing the name make the completion works correctly in the cases I tried.  If I care about portability when writing scripts, I've chosen zsh for its interactive features and I don't mind being dependent on them, in fact I was half expecting a setopt or an environment variable as a solution.

Comment: @schily, as already discussed with you elsewhere, pdksh, bash, zsh all had a `builtin` builtin with zsh semantic long before ksh93 was even released. It's ksh93 which deviated from the established de-facto standard then. zsh's `command` command also predates POSIX' AFAIK.

Comment: Do you have a pointer to that discussion? `command` existed in ksh88 already and the behavior of the `zsh` builtin `builtin` would better be implemented via e.g. `command -b ...`